# Is there a proper order of davening for one who learns before minyan?

Tags: tefilla, korbanos-ketores-prayers

For someone who learns before davening with a minyan, is it proper to say korbanot before learning? Or is it more proper to wait until after learning to say it with the minyanim. I am curious if there are any sources on this.

Further, would it depend on what time he is saying it? I.e., maybe he can not yet say korbanot if it is too early in the morning.

Comment: [Halachipedia](https://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=When_Is_the_Earliest_and_Latest_Time_to_Pray%3F): One can only say Korbanot during the day, meaning after Olot HaShachar which is 72 minutes (in Shaot Zmaniot) before HaNetz.

Answer (score 1):

The [Ben Ish Chai (I Mikaitz 11)](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Ben_Ish_Hai%2C_Halachot_1st_Year%2C_Miketz.11?lang=bi) says that one should say korbonos immediately before pisukai dizimrah:

> טוב לסמוך אמירת פסוקים של הודו לפרשת התמיד ואיזהו מקומן בכל מה דאפשר יען כי בתמיד של שחר היו אומרים מ"הודו לה'" עד "ובנביאי אל תרעו", ובתמיד של בין הערבים היו אומרים מ"שירו לה' כל הארץ" עד "והלל לה'", ועל פי הסוד יש טעם בפסוקים אלו כדי להפריד הקליפות מעל הקדושה, ומי שיש לו איזה סיבה שלא יוכל להקדים לבא לבית הכנסת להתחיל התפלה מפרשת העקידה עם הציבור שהוא מוכרח להתחיל בביתו לבדו עד "ה' מלך", יחזור ויאמר פעם שנית פסוקים של הודו כדי להסמיכם לזמירות על פי הסוד, ובביתו גם כן מוכרח היה לאומרם כדי לסומכם עם פרשת התמיד, ושאר קרבנות.
>
> It is good to connect saying the pesukim of Hodu to the chapter of the Tamid and Eizehu Mikoman as much as possible... and one who for some reason can not come early to the synagogue to start the prayers from the chapter of the Akeida with the congregation, and must start at home until Hashem melech, he should go back and say a second time the pesukim of Hodu in order to connect them to the psalms, according to the sod, and in his house he also must say them to connect them to the chapter of the Tamid and the rest of the korbonos.

Comment: That's not a great summary of what he says. Does he ever indicate saying Hodu twice is at all inferior? It's more like "one should say korbonos immediately before pisukai dizimrah *if you daven Sfard and don't want to bother to say it twice*"

Comment: This doesn't seem to apply to those davening Nusach Ashkenaz

Comment: I can't say I understand the importance that the BIH is giving this; he says it's according to *sod!*

Comment: Why shouldn't this apply to nusach ashkenaz? Also, he mentions nusach ashkinaz on the next line, and doesn't seem to say that anything would change.

Comment: In nusach ashkenaz we say hodu after baruch sheamar in pesukei dizimra, not as part of korbanos.